# Cant find or load main class

Tags: java

When I try to run a java program in the cmd it displays the messege "Could not find or load main class". 
The problem occurs when there is a package involved in the program, otherwise it works fine.

The code is:

```
package myPackage;

public class index {

public static void main(String [] args){

    System.out.println("Hello World");
}
}
```

I've tried writting in cmd: javac (name of package) . Class name, but still doesnt work.

Comment: what is the file name of java program?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What does "Could not find or load main class" mean?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18093928/what-does-could-not-find-or-load-main-class-mean)

Answer (score 1):

The issue was that the class path needs to be set for each command (javac and java):

**Attempted Steps**

```
Compile index.java from the top_level. do not use sub package.

$javac -cp . importpackage/subpackage/index.java
```

Comment: Im not quite sure if I understand the answer because it produces another error.

Comment: java -cp import myPackage/index.java

Comment: the error is: could not fine or load main class myPackage.index.java

Comment: Also, in the cmd I am in the myPackage folder. Is that correct ?